# missunderstanding mvc default binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding, jquery-chosen

I have multiselect jquery plagin ([Choosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)) and when I use it in 'Multiple Select' mode I expect in controller next values:

```
    posted string = 'value1,value2...'
```

really have

```
    posted string = 'value2'
```

only if I reffer directly to FormCollection I'll get expected values as below:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult TagSearech(/*string tagSelect*/FormCollection c)
    {
      // only one value here
      // string[] names = tagSelect.Split(',');

      // as expected: value1,....
       string expectedValue = c['tagSelect'];

        return View();
    }
```

I cant understand what might cause this behavior.

**EDIT**

Here is View:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("TagSearech", "Tag"))
    {
       @Html.DropDownList("tagSelect", Model, new { @class = "chzn-select",  data_placeholder = "tag names", multiple = "" })
       <input  type="submit"/>
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC will attempt to bind the input data on the URL into the model. I haven't seen how Chosen.js posts the data back to the server, but essentially its coming in in the wrong format, so MVC binds the first element it sees to the string Model.

The FormsCollection retrieves all of the data that was posted in the URL, which is why all of your selected values can be seen there.

Did you try changing the incoming model from string to string[], and see if all of the items are bound to the array?

Comment: so,idea with array works fine.May be this is not wrong format - author made plagin work in such way.seems like there are several fields with the same name and different values.

Comment: In which case MVC is correctly binding the first value into the field, but then doesn't know what to do with the rest. The string Array will work because the binder can continue to assign values into the variable with the same name.